How can I downgrade fwupdmgr in Ubuntu?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and it has fwupdmgr version 1.19.6.
I have tried downgrading the fwupd tool. But none of it works.
Tried to remove the tool and reinstall using snap tool with the version I need. But it throws error when I do it that way.
Is there any way to downgrade fwupd tool.?

"none of it works" and "it throws error" are much too vague to offer useful advice. Details are essential, so please don't omit them. When describing errors, please show the complete, accurate input and output. Please don't make us guess or speculate.

See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/fwupd-snap on how to install the snap version -- it sounds like you have both installed.
